# "Add" button inside foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I am following [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) and would like to move the "Add" button into the `foreach` loop.  So, every row will have a button that can add a new record on the end.

My problem is that moving the form seems to break everything.  I have [this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/GxNp9/1/) now:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pages, visible: pages().length > 0">   
    <div class='page'>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <form data-bind="submit: addPage">
            <button type="submit">Add Page</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
<script>
var pageCounter=1;

function Page(data) {
    this.title=ko.observable("Page "+data.title);
}

function PageListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.pages = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Operations
    self.addPage = function() {
        self.pages.push(new Page({title: pageCounter}));
        pageCounter++;
    };
    self.removePage = function(page) { self.pages.remove(page) };

    self.addPage();
}

ko.applyBindings(new PageListViewModel());
</script>
```

If you move the `<form>` outside the `foreach` then the button functions properly, but there is only the 1 button.  How can I change it so that there is an "Add Page" button on each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to use the $parent reference as follow :

```
<form data-bind="submit:$parent.addPage">
    <button type="submit">Add Page</button>
</form>
```

This will call addPage on the PageListViewModel object.

Comment: @Cory, Yes, $root works in this case. But its not necessary to use the $root if you need the $parent.

Comment: I mentioned it so that if `addPage()` always exists on the root view model, then it would be safer to use `$root` in case the nesting of the `Page` view model became more complex (e.g. the root was now the grand-parent of the `Page`; it would be cumbersome to write `$parent.$parent` or `$parents[1]`).

Answer (score 3):

Change your form binding to `<form data-bind="submit: $root.addPage">`. Note the addition of `$root`, which says: call the `addPage()` method on the "root" view model.

Also, you don't need to bind to a form to make this work. It would be much more succinct to simply use a button with a click binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pages, visible: pages().length > 0">   
    <div class='page'>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.addPage">Add Page</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxNp9/2/) for you that shows a working example of the above.